In which book of the Vorkosigan Saga does Miles says something like "It changed my opinion of media"
I believe remembering a scene in the Vorkosigan Saga where someone asks Miles whether seeing the depiction of his parents in media/journals (or any synonym) changed his opinion about his parents, and Miles answering that it did not, but it did change his opinion of media/journals.
Alas, I don't remember the exact wording, and is seems that the word "parents" did not appear in this dialogue.
Indeed I have the entire Saga in electronic form, and a search engine for "parents", book after book, did not identify the scene. Neither did "Count Vorkosigan" nor "Countess Vorkosigan". So other words must have been used.
I also tried "media" or "journals" or "journalists" and also "opinion" and none worked.
Can anyone find this scene ? Any suggestion of a keyword that would actually allow me to find it would be accepted. Just the keyword "news", however, gave so many occurrences that I gave up checking.

My gut tells me this was a conversation with Ekaterin, but if not probably one of Miles' galactic paramours like Rowan.  (Though probably not Rowan, given the plot of that book.)

Komarr (1998).

"I believe I've seen your mother a few times on the holovid," she offered after a moment. "Sitting next to your father on reviewing platforms and the like. Mostly some years ago, when he was still regent. Does it seem strange . . . does it give you a very different view of your parents, to see them on vid?"
"No," he said. "It gives me a very different view of holovids."


Found by uploading the ebook series into calibre then using the Quality Check plugin to search all the books simultaneously for words like "your family" "your mother" and finally, "your parents".

Thanks ! How could have missed it ! I did look for "parents" in every single book of the Saga ! Too fast, obviously. Now that I know it is in Komarr, I found it in a few seconds !

Thanks, good to know I was right (as far as that went).
